# Display name is not reflected on Vertex pipelines UI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have a job that uses `CustomContainerTrainingJobRunOp` with example code

```py
def custom_job(task_name, env, machine_type):
    from google_cloud_pipeline_components.aiplatform import (
        CustomContainerTrainingJobRunOp,
    )

    op = CustomContainerTrainingJobRunOp(
        project=PROJECT_ID,
        display_name=task_name,
        location=REGION,
        machine_type=machine_type,
        replica_count=1,
        container_uri=IMAGE_URI,
        staging_bucket=STAGING,
    )
    return op

@dsl.pipeline(
    name="name-of-the-pipeline", # This is ok
    description="some job",
    pipeline_root=PIPELINE_ROOT,
)
def pipeline(project_id: str = PROJECT_ID, gcp_region: str = REGION):
    bq_task = custom_job("setup_bq", "stg")
compiler.Compiler().compile(pipeline_func=pipeline, package_path='file.json')
```

In the UI, the job name is shown as

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

That's because the customcontainertrainingjobop pipeline component actually goes and spins up a container job in the "Training pipeline" section of Vertex.
The display name you are changing there refers to the name shown in the "Training pipeline" section.
To change the name of the Vertex pipeline component itself, you need to add .set_display_name("somenameorother") to the end of the component as shown here:

```
CustomContainerTrainingJobRunOp(
    display_name="Training_pipeline_name",
    container_uri="whatever:latest",
    project="whatever",
    location="whatever",
    machine_type="n-expensive-8",
    base_output_dir="somebucket",
    staging_bucket="somebucket",
).set_display_name("lobster_barbados")
```

It can also be done by outputting the pipeline as a config file and then altering it with find and replace, if there are other hard to find settings you want to mess with. This isn't the best way to do it, the above is the correct way, but I often use things like:

```
def _modify_task_name(pipeline_json, old_name, new_name):
pipeline_json["pipelineSpec"]["root"]["dag"]["tasks"][old_name]["taskInfo"][
    "name"
] = new_name
return pipeline_json
```

To make more arcane changes that I can't find the incredibly poor google docs for.